# Unexpected token { plus buyHelper and loadCode is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, unexpected-token

I was watching a tutorial and followed his code but named the variables and functions myself, but after i did the `buyHelper` function, my `loadCode` function stopped working and it kept saying the "{" was unexpected. Please help. (I did all the code in one file except for the css because it wouldnt work externally)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(){
            document.getElementById("amount").value = codeAmount;
                document.title = codeAmount + " Codes"
    }

    var codeAmount = 0;
    var codeHelper = 0;

    function timer(){
        codeAmount = codeAmount + codeHelper;
        update()
    }

    setInterval(timer, 1000);
</script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>0 Codes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clickerGame2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Click to get JavaScript code!</h1>

        <h2>Use your code to get upgrades!</h2>

        <a href=# onclick="addJS()"><img 
src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmww2.png" alt="JS Logo" width="150" 
height="150" class="pulse"></a>

        <br><br>
        You Have:
        <input type="text" id="amount" disabled style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addJS(){
                codeAmount = codeAmount + 1;
              update()
            }
        </script>
        lines of code.
        <br><br>
        <button><a href=# onclick="saveCode()" class="white">Save!</a>
</button>

        <button><a href=# onclick="loadCode()"class="white">Load!</a>
</button>
        <br><br>

        <p>Pay someone to help code!</p>

        <button><a href=# onclick="buyHelper()">Helper</a></button>

        <p id="helperCost"></p>

        <p id="helperAmount">You have 0 helpers.</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function saveCode(){
                localStorage.setItem("codeAmount", codeAmount);
            }
            function loadCode(){
                codeAmount = localStorage.getItem("codeAmount");
                codeAmount = parseInt(codeAmount);
                update();
            }

            function buyHelper(){
                if (codeAmount >= ((codeHelper+1)*12){
                    codeAmount = codeAmount - ((codeHelper+!)*12);
                    codeHelper = codeHelper + 1;
                    update();
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `buyHelper` function you have 2 mistakes. First one you are missing close parenthesis in `if` statement and second one is in next line you used exclamation mark instead of 1

Here is the function after editing:

```
function buyHelper(){
    if (codeAmount >= ((codeHelper+1)*12)){
        codeAmount = codeAmount - ((codeHelper+1)*12);
        codeHelper = codeHelper + 1;
        update();
    }
}
```